# Why doesn't the IEEEtran document class recognize "definition" environments?

Tags: ieeetran

I have an IEEEtran document class. I want to put a simple definition inside the document:

```
\begin{definition}
blab bla
\end{definition}
```

I am getting the error below:

*Environment definition undefined. \begin{definition}*

Comment: The class defines *no* theorem-like environment. Use `\newtheorem`.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

[`IEEEtran`](http://ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran) defines its own environments which is used to replace existing ones (like `enumerate`, `itemize`, etc.). However, it doesn't define any `definition` environment. You can do so by using `\newtheorem`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{IEEEtran}% http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ieeetran
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}
\begin{document}
\begin{definition}
Here is a definition.
\end{definition}
\end{document}​
```

Comment: I prefer to the `\theoremstyle{break}` in the package `ntheorem`. However, if I use this in `IEEEtran`, its theorem/definition numbers are prefixed by the Roman section number (II.5) instead of original Arabic number (2.5). How can I get both `2.5` and the `break` style?

Comment: @hengxin: I assume your sections are also enumerated in Roman numerals. You can change the section numbering to be Arabic via `\renewcommand{\thesection}{\arabic{section}}`, or you can just have Arabic section numbering in the theorems via `\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{theorem}}`. Then your numbering will be inconsistent though. Does this work?

Comment: I tried `\usepackage[thmmarks]{ntheorem}
\theoremstyle{break}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\renewcommand{\thetheorem}{\arabic{section}.\arabic{theorem}}` in IEEEtran and I got only the number "1.0": (1) Roman section numbering (2) no the keyword "Theorem"; (3) counting goes from 0 instead of 1; (4) no break style. Did I make mistakes? BTW, I decided to follow IEEEtran's default environment: (1) Roman section numbering (2) Arabic.Ababic theorem numbering (3) no break style. Thank you all the same.

Comment: hum, I still prefer to the following theorem environment in IEEEtrans: (1) Roman section numbering (2) with keywords "Theorem"/"Definition" in bold (3) no indent of the keywords (4) Arabic.Arabic theorem numbering (5) with break style (6) counting goes from 1 within each section. So, I am demanding too much. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @hengxin: I suggest asking a [follow-up](http://goo.gl/vWjuk) question.